# Allow access only from specific url in ASP.NET core web service

Tags: web-services, asp.net-core

I have to make web service in ASP.NET core and it should be accessible only from specific URL. No authentication with username and password.
I understand that I have to create some kind of custom filtering with middleware to achive this. But how do I get the callers URL address?

Comment: A web service can be accessible by a lot of different kind of applications and you can not check them by url. You could check them by IP.

Comment: @pitaridis How can I get the callers IP address?

Comment: @dace The current HttpContext contains a property called Connection of type `ConnectionInfo`. It contains all the connection info of the underlying request.

Comment: Have you looked at CORS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ConfigureServices you can use a CORS policy to only allow specific origins. (Change the IP address to be the IP or machine name that can call the service)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddCors(action =>
    {
        action.AddPolicy("origin", policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins(new string[] { "10.1.0.1" });
        });
    });
}
```

And then use it in Configure:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseCors("origin");
    ...
}
```